# how to perform right join in tmap talend DI

Tags: talend

Suppose two input source one is main and other one lookup. can you plase advice how to perform right join in tmap component in talend DI.
In tmap component by default left outer join and you can choose inner join.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why right join? Sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Trying to read  all rows from the right table (lookup table), with the matching rows in the left table (Main table). I can do that in SQL server but I am trying archive in tmap and not able to achieve.

Comment: you can always reverse your tables in tmap - make your current lookup as main table and main as lookup table and then do left outer join...

Answer (score 1):

You can switch (right click the lookup link and modify the connection as main) your current lookup as **main** and main connection as **lookup**. Then you can do left outer join as right outer join.

For reference [check here](https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-tmap-component-joins.html).

Comment: what if i wanted to filter out all the non matching records from both look up and main table, very useful when you are doing synchronization

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do right now @SerakShiferaw